# Element viewStateWrapper with id = ajax-view-state must exist : Error

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, ajax

I have an visualforce page in which i am rerendering the apex form element on dropdown change.
This page works fine until their is an validation error ( i am validating with jquery validate). Once validation throws an error, next post back works fine but after that no ajax calls are executed.

Any help would be appreciate.

```
           <apex:form id="frmMain" onsubmit="removeSpanForm();" styleClass="frmMain form-1">

                    <fieldset>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="" id="countryclass">
                                <p>
                                <apex:actionRegion >
                                    <apex:selectList title="Select Country" id="ddlCountry" value="{!usableAccount.Country}"  styleClass="ddlCombo" size="1" >
                                      <apex:selectOptions value="{!countries}"/>
                                      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setCountryAndStateData}" rerender="frmMain" />
                                    </apex:selectList>
                                 </apex:actionRegion>
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>
                                    <apex:inputText title="Trading Name (Required)" id="txtTradingName" value="{!usableAccount.Name}" />   
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>
                                    <apex:inputText title="Legal Business Name" label="Legal Bussiness Name" value="{!usableAccount.LegalName}"/>
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li style="display:{!IF(usableAccount.Country == 'Australia', 'block', 'none')}">
                                <p>
                                    <apex:inputText title="ABN (Required)" id="txtAbn" value="{!usableAccount.ABN}" />
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li style="display:{!IF(usableAccount.Country == 'Australia', 'block', 'none')}">
                                <p>
                                    <apex:inputText title="ACN" id="txtACN" label="ACN" value="{!usableAccount.ACN}"  />
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>
                                    <apex:inputText title="Region" label="Region" value="{!usableAccount.Region}" />
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>
                                    <apex:inputText title="Address (Required)" id="txtAddress1"  value="{!usableAccount.Address1}"/>
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>
                                    <apex:inputText title="Address2" value="{!usableAccount.Address2}"/>
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>
                                    <apex:inputText title="City/Suburb (Required)" id="txtCitySubrub" label="City/Suburb" value="{!usableAccount.Suburb}"/>
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p class="width-half stateClass">
                                    <apex:outputPanel id="divStates">
                                        <apex:selectList id="states" value="{!usableAccount.State}" styleClass="ddlStates ddlCombo" size="1" >
                                          <apex:selectOptions value="{!states}"/>
                                        </apex:selectList>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                </p>
                                <p class="width-half postcodeClass">
                                    <apex:inputText title="PostCode (Required)" id="txtPostCode" label="Post Code" value="{!usableAccount.Postcode}"/>
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="box-submit">
                                <apex:commandButton id="btnSubmit" title="State__c" action="{!submit}" value="Next"/>
                                <apex:commandLink styleClass="link-1"  id="btnBackToContactInfo" action="{!backToContactInfo}" value="Back"/>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </fieldset>

            </apex:form>
<script type="text/javascript">      
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();


    function removeSpanForm()
    {
    /*
        if('[id$=frmMain]') {
            $j('.field-validation-error').remove();
        $j('input').removeClass('input-validation-error');
        $j('select').removeClass('input-validation-error');
        }
        */
    }

    function removeSpan(){
        /*
        $j('.field-validation-error').remove();
        $j('input').removeClass('input-validation-error');
        $j('select').removeClass('input-validation-error');
        return true;
        */
    }

    function setFormValidations(){
        /*
        handlePageMes();
         $j('[id$=frmMain]').validate({
            errorClass: "field-validation-error",
            errorElement: "span",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                },
            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                    $j(element).addClass('input-validation-error');

            },
            unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight
                $j(element).removeClass('input-validation-error');
            },
             messages:
                {
                    'companyInfo:layout:frmMain:ddlCountry': {
                        required: '<span class="input-validation-error " style="display:none !important">Email is required.</span>'
                    },

                    'companyInfo:layout:frmMain:txtTradingName': {

                        required:  '<span class="input-validation-error cPassword" style="display:none !important">Password is required.</span>'
                    },
                    'companyInfo:layout:frmMain:txtAddress1': {

                        required: '<span class="input-validation-error cPassword" style="display:none !important">Confirm Password is required.</span>'
                    },
                }
        });

        $j('[id$=ddlCountry]').rules("add",{ required: true });
        $j('[id$=txtTradingName]').rules("add",{ required: true });
        $j('[id$=txtAddress1]').rules("add",{ required: true });
        */
    }

    $j(document).ready(function(){



        setFormValidations();

        $j(".field-validation-error" ).live( "mouseover", function() {
            $j(this).find('.input-validation-error').attr("style", "display:block !important");
        });

        $j(".field-validation-error" ).live( "mouseout", function() {
            $j(this).find('.input-validation-error').attr("style", "display:none !important");
        });




        //$j('[id$=txtAbn]').rules("add",{ required: true });


        //$j('[id$=txtCitySubrub]').rules("add",{ required: true });
        //$j('[id$=states]').rules("add",{ required: true });
        //$j('[id$=txtPostCode]').rules("add",{ required: true });

         $j(".frmMain ").live( "submit", isValidForm);
    });

    function isValidForm()
    {
    alert($j('[id$=txtTradingName]').val());
        var bValid = true;
        if($j.trim($j('[id$=txtTradingName]').val()) == '')
        {
        alert();
            return false;
        }
        return bValid;
    }

</script>
<style>

    .ddlStates {
        width: 127px;
    }
    .ddlStates option {
        width: 127px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A conventional way of adding JQuery listeners to DOM objects is to use the `ready` function. But that only runs when the page loads; it does not run when parts of the page are updated via the re-render mechanism. But there is an `oncomplete` available where you can call some JavaScript code when the re-render has completed..

So the general solution to this problem is to factor out the JQuery initialisation into a separate function and call that function from both places:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setCountryAndStateData}"
    rerender="frmMain" oncomplete="addJQueryLogic()" />

function addJQueryLogic() {
    setFormValidations();

    $j(".field-validation-error" ).live( "mouseover", function() {
        $j(this).find('.input-validation-error').attr("style","display:block !important");
    });

    ...
}

$j(document).ready(addJQueryLogic);
```

The title of your question doesn't match the detailed information. One or other should probably be changed.